# Save values generated via API as custom meta fields

Tags: custom-field, post-meta

I'm using the [IMDB Connecter](https://wordpress.org/plugins/imdb-connector/) plugin to grab meta data for movies and I'm wondering if I can save some of the information it generates as custom meta data.

Basically, I want to be able to save the "Language" and "Actors" information generated by the plugin in meta fields with the same name so that posts are searchable using these values.

This is how I currently output the data in my single.php file;

```
$imdb = get_field('imdb_id'); // IMDB movie ID is saved as a custom meta value
$imdbInfo = get_imdb_connector_movie($imdb);
$actors = $imdbInfo['actors']; // Gets an array of actor names
$language = $imdbInfo['languages']; // Gets an array of languages
```

Is it possible to save these values as custom meta?

Any nudge in the right direction would be most appreciated

Comment: You can save post meta using `update_post_meta` https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/update_post_meta

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `wp_insert_post` hook to run when a post is saved:

```
function wpse_188435_save_movie_data( $post_id ) {
    if ( $imdb = get_field( 'imdb_id', $post_id ) ) {
        if ( $imdbInfo = get_imdb_connector_movie( $imdb ) ) {
            if ( isset( $imdbInfo['actors'] ) )
                update_post_meta( $post_id, 'actors', $imdbInfo['actors'] );
            if ( isset( $imdbInfo['languages'] ) )
                update_post_meta( $post_id, 'languages', $imdbInfo['languages'] );
        }
    }
}

add_action( 'wp_insert_post', 'wpse_188435_save_movie_data', 50 /* Late priority, will ensure ACF has saved all data first */ );
```